# $I^{-1}M \cong Hom_R(I,M)$, $R$:Dedekind domain, $I$:fractional ideal of $R$, $M$:torsion free $R$module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, let $I$ be fractional ideal of $R$.
Let $M$ be torsion free $R$module.
Then I want to prove $I^{-1}M \cong Hom_R(I,M)$.

Let $ \phi : I^{-1}M→Hom_R(I,M)$ be given by $x→\phi_x:α→αx$.
This is clearly homomorphism and injection because if $αx=αy$,$α(x-y)=0$ thus $x=y$ because $M$ is torsion free.
I'm having trouble to prove **surjectivity**.

If this is an famous proposition, I'll also appreciated if you could tell me reference. Thank you for your help.

Comment: One approach is to prove this is an isomorphism $\mathfrak p$-locally for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $M$. That is, prove that the homomorphism $I^{-1}M\otimes_RR_{\mathfrak p}\to Hom_R(I,M)\otimes_RR_{\mathfrak p}$ is an isomorphism for each prime $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: This question is also answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344749/operatornamehom-r-mathfraka-m-is-isomorphic-to-mathfraka-1m-if?rq=1

Comment: No, it's link gives just reference but reference is not valid now.

Comment: Reference link is invalid now.