# Tensor product of Hom-module and another ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, noetherian

Let $A$ be a local noetherian ring, $B$ and $C$ are finitely generated $A$-algebras and $M$ is a finitely generated $B$-module. Is the natural morphism $\mathrm{Hom}_B(M,B) \otimes_A C \to \mathrm{Hom}_B(M,B \otimes_A C)$ injective? If necessary, assume that $B$ is flat over $A$.

EDIT: Please note that the homomorphisms are as $B$-modules instead of $A$-modules as mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81429/hom-and-tensor-with-a-flat-module).

Comment: Please use the search function - this question and related questions have appeared a couple of times. A counterexample is (usually) $M = B^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry, I forgot to mention, I assume $M$ is a finitely generated $B$-module.

Comment: The more relevant difference between your question and the linked question is actually that you are assuming that $B$, rather than $C$, is flat.

Comment: As the above comment seems to suggest, once you replace N by an A-algebra B, in the linked question, the natural homomorphism becomes one of B-modules.

Comment: There is no duplicate now, so one can skip that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample.  Let $k$ be a field and take $A=B=k[x]/(x^2)$ and $M=C=k$ (considered as an $A$-algebra via $x\mapsto 0$).  Then $\mathrm{Hom}_B(M,B)\cong k$ (spanned by $1\mapsto x$), so $\mathrm{Hom}_B(M,B) \otimes_A C\cong k$ as well.  But $1\mapsto x$ maps to $0$ in $\mathrm{Hom}_B(M,B \otimes_A C)$, since $x=0$ in $B\otimes_A C=C$.

On the other hand, if you assume $C$ is flat, then the map always is injective (in fact, it is an isomorphism).  Indeed, you can note that there is a natural isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_B(M,B)\otimes_A C\cong \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,B)\otimes_B (B\otimes_A C)$ that is compatible with the canonical maps to $\mathrm{Hom}_B(M,B \otimes_A C)\cong \mathrm{Hom}_B(M,B\otimes_B (B \otimes_A C))$, so you are reduced to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81429/hom-and-tensor-with-a-flat-module?lq=1) over the ring $B$ with $N=B$ and $P=B\otimes_A C$ (which is flat over $B$ since $C$ is flat over $A$).