# Is it true that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N) \otimes_R P=\operatorname{Hom}_R(M ,N \otimes P)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M, N, P$ be modules over a commutative ring $R$. The above identity is true for $R$ a field:

Since the RHS $\cong$ (by passing to double dual)  $$\operatorname{Hom}(N^* \otimes P^*, M^*)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(P^*,\operatorname{Hom}(N^*,M^*)) \cong P^{**}  \otimes\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)\cong P \otimes\operatorname{Hom}(M,N).$$

In a couple examples that I worked out, it held true but the steps do not hold true if $N$ and $M$ have torsion.  Is the identity true?

---

edit:  I had originally made a mistake when writing my question.  I have changed the question title to make it correct.  Originally I had written $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N) \otimes_R P=\operatorname{Hom}_R(M\otimes P,N)$ which as Qiaochu Yuan remarks is ludicrous (for the vector space case $RHS= P^*\otimes\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$). Other than cosmetic changes the body of the text remain unchanged.

Comment: In your title the LHS is covariantly functorial in $P$ but the RHS is contravariantly functorial. Also, you seem to be assuming that your modules are dualizable; over a field this means they're finite-dimensional and in general it means they're finitely generated projective.

Comment: Sorry I had written the right steps but the wrong question.  I meant to write

Comment: I meant to write $Hom(M,N) \otimes_R P =Hom_R(M,N \otimes P)$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81429/hom-and-tensor-with-a-flat-module

Comment: In the special case in which $M=P$ and $N=R$, what you want is that $P^*\otimes_RP$ be the same as $\hom_R(P,P)$, and that is not true even over a field when $P$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: If, on the other hand, $M$ is a torsion module over a domain $R$, $P=M$ and $N=R$, then $P^*=0$ so that $P^*\otimes P=0$ yet $\hom(P,P)$ is not zero. You can take $M$ finitely generated here.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226343/does-module-hom-commute-with-tensor-product-in-the-second-variable/226363#226363), this does not hold in general, but it does hold if any of the following sets of hypotheses holds:

- $P$ is finitely presented projective,
- $M$ is finitely presented and $P$ is flat,
- $P$ is finitely presented and $M$ is projective.

As an example of the second case, $P$ can be a localization of the base ring, and you get that if $M$ is finitely presented then hom commutes with localization.

Your argument can be made to work under the additional assumption of *dualizability*, which for modules is equivalent to being finitely presented projective; see for example [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/dualizable-objects-and-morphisms/) for details. But you assume in your argument that $M, N, P$ are all dualizable, and as mentioned above you actually only need to assume that $P$ is dualizable, although this doesn't cover all cases of interest.

Comment: Any hints on how the proof goes for point 3?

Answer (score 1):

It is true if $P$ is finitely generated projective, for instance. In this case you have $P\oplus Q=R^n$ and the statement boils down to prove
$$\def\H{\operatorname{Hom}_R}
\H(M,N)\otimes R^n\cong\H(M,N\otimes_RR^n)
$$
which is almost obvious.

If $R$ is a field, $P$ finitely generated projective means $P$ is finite dimensional.

In general you can only say there's a natural map
$$
\H(M,N)\otimes_RP\to\H(M,N\otimes_RP)
$$
given by the bilinear map
$$
\H(M,N)\times P\to\H(M,N\otimes_RP),
\qquad
(f,p)\mapsto \widetilde{(f,p)}
$$
where
$$
\widetilde{(f,p)}\colon m\mapsto f(m)\otimes p
$$

Comment: I the first part you said that it is enough to prove for $R^n$. That I got. From there how it follows for $P$ where $P$ satisfies $P \oplus Q=R^n$.

Comment: @AnupamAh Hom commutes with finite direct sums

Comment: For R^n I was able to prove. From this how can I prove for P where P satisfies $P \oplus Q=R^n$.  If it is true for $R^n$ then $Hom(L,M) \otimes (P\oplus Q)$ isomorphic to $Hom(L, M \otimes (P \oplus Q)$. From this How can I conclude that  $Hom(L,M) \otimes  P$ isomorphic to $Hom(L,M \otimes P)$

Comment: @AnupamAh Consider the appropriate map diagrams and see that they consist of isomorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to put Prof. Suarez-Alvarez's comment as an answer.

Right so it is not true in the case for infinite dimensional vector spaces because I need to use double duality to get the identity $Hom(V,W)=V^* \otimes W$.  In more detail $Hom(V,W) = Hom (V, Hom(W^*,R))=Hom(V \otimes W^* ,R)=(V\otimes W^*)^*=V^* \otimes W$.  I used this identity in the second isomorphism in my question.

Nor is it true when $M=\mathbb{Z}/2$, $N=\mathbb{Z}$, $P=\mathbb{Z}/2$, for LHS=$Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2,\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2=0\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2=0$ and $RHS=Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2,\mathbb{Z}/2)=(\mathbb{Z/2})^4$.