# Isomorphic for free modules implies for projective

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

I have if $F$ is a free $R$-module then $\mathrm{Hom}(L,M) \otimes F$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Hom}(L,M \otimes F)$. Then how can I conclude that $\mathrm{Hom}(L,M) \otimes P$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Hom}(L,M \otimes P)$ where $P$ is finitely generated projective?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728363/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$
If $P$ is a finitely generated projective $R$-module, then it is also finitely presented: Take a surjection $R^n\twoheadrightarrow P$ with kernel $Q$. Then $R^n = Q\oplus P$ as $P$ is projective. As the projection $R^n\rightarrow Q$ is surjective, $Q$ is also finitely generated. Thus, we obtain an exact sequence $R^m\rightarrow R^n\rightarrow P \rightarrow 0$.
We always have a natural morphism $\Hom(L,M)\otimes N\rightarrow \Hom(L,M\otimes N)$ for all $R$-modules $L, M, N$. The above exact sequence gives by functoriality a commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\Hom(L,M)\otimes R^m & \longrightarrow & \Hom(L,M)\otimes R^n & \longrightarrow & \Hom(L,M)\otimes P & \longrightarrow & 0\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
\Hom(L,M\otimes R^m) & \longrightarrow & \Hom(L,M\otimes R^n) & \longrightarrow & \Hom(L,M\otimes P) & \longrightarrow & 0
\end{array}
$$
Since the left two vertical arrows are isomorphisms, the five Lemma (or direct computation) tells us that also the right vertical arrow is an isomorphism.

(**Note:** The morphism $\Hom(L,M\otimes R^n)\rightarrow \Hom(L,M\otimes P)$ in the second row is surjective because $R^n\rightarrow P$ is a split surjection.)